# end of an Exe file in C++

Tags: c++, iostream, exe

I am writing a C++ program to read an exe file. I wrote it and I test it on a text file instead of exe file. it was true.

when I test it with an exe file I understand that my exe file have **0x00** value in it (not at its end). so my while loop stop before end of file because I used:

```
class A{
private:
ifstream myFile;
void Read(char *filename)
};

void A::Read(char *str)
{
myFile.open(str,ios::binary);

    while (!myFile.eof())
    {
       InputFile.get(ch);
       myString.push_back(ch);
    }
}
```

what should I do? if I should use size of the file, how can i get it?

Comment: Could you add code showing how you're trying to read the file?

Comment: my code is big so I wrote it's summary!

Comment: How are you storing the result you read?

Comment: I am saving it in a in a vector<char>!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a hunch here, but my suspicion is that you're actually reading the whole file correctly, but measuring it wrong.

File reading (with binary mode) won't stop on a 0-byte, but there are several string related methods that will.

For example, you can't measure the size of a binary "blob" using strlen(), you can't copy it using strcpy().

Without seeing the actual way you're storing and measuring the data, it's hard to see where things go wrong, but I strongly suspect that you're actually reading the whole file correctly if you're using binary mode.

Comment: Yes I was cout the vector, and the 0x00 was end of string. THANKS ALL & SORRY ALL FOR MY LOW IQ.

Answer (score 2):

You must open the file stream with the `std::ios::binary` mode flag.

Comment: how can I do that? std::ios::binary::ifstream Myfile?

Comment: I tried InputFile.open(_fileName,ios::in | ios::binary); but still it stop in 0x00

Answer (score 2):

As [James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151292/james-mcnellis) pointed out you need to open the file in binary mode: Try something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("main.obj", std::ios_base::binary);

    std::streamsize bytes_read = 0;
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        while (!in.eof())
        {
            char buf[1024];

            // Use unformatted read.
            in.read(buf, 1024);

            if (in.gcount() > 0)
            {
                // The first 'in.gcount()' chars in
                // 'buf' were read.
                bytes_read += in.gcount();
            }
        }
    }
    in.close();

    std::cout << "bytes read=" << bytes_read << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Example modified to use `get()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("main.obj", std::ios_base::binary);
    std::streamsize bytes_read = 0;
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        while (!in.eof())
        {
            in.get();
            if (1 == in.gcount())
            {
                bytes_read++;
            }
        }
    }
    in.close();
    std::cout << "bytes read=" << bytes_read << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Tested and works correctly.

Comment: tnx for answer, I tried a thing like in my question, it has still that trouble! :(

Comment: You need to show how you are reading the file: you **must** use unformatted read.

Comment: you don't think it's because i declared myFile in class A and open it in Read with ios::binary? ir doesnt work yet!

Comment: No, that won't be the cause. There is no `myFile.is_open()` check and without seeing the actual code it's difficult to identify the problem.

Comment: It's Open and it read bytes I cout it, but when it reaches to 0x00 it stops and think it's end of file

Comment: How can I send the project to you if you want to look at it?

Comment: Do you check the return value of `get()` and terminate loop if 0? Are there any `break`s inside the `while`?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to opening the file in binary mode, the current code has a subtle bug which will cause the last character in the file to be read twice. The problem is that the `myFile.eof()` call does not do what you think it does. It does not tell you when you're at the end of the file. It tells you that you have tried to read *beyond* the end of the file. The idiomatic way to write a read-until-eof loop in C++ is:

```
while (myFile.get(ch))
    myString.push_back(ch);
```

`get` returns an `istream` reference which, in this context, is implicitly convertible to `bool` and is used to indicate that there is no more data to read.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, The program read all the bytes but I `cout` that bytes in a `vector<char>`, So it's obvious I saw just bytes before *0x00*.